# AES CBC: how shall i get to know with AES CBC method, the received Cipher Text is padded or not

Tags: aes, cbc, padding

Algorithm: *AES - CBC mode with PKCS7 padding*

KeyValue:

```
10a58869d74be5a374cf867cfb473859
```

IV:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000
```

Plaintext:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000
```

Expected ciphertext:

```
6d251e6944b051e04eaa6fb4dbf78465
```

Three steps are used to compute the CBC Encrypt as mentioned below:

```
CBC_Start(Key,IV)
CBC_Update(Plaintext, plaintext length, Ciphertext, Ciphertextlength)
CBC_Finish(Ciphertext, Ciphertextlength)
```

Ciphertext is obtained when the update is finished, but when finish is completed, the ciphertext obtained is different from what is expected.

Why is this happening?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use some specific crypto-library. Could you tell us which one?

Comment: APIs that use the init,update,finish model require that the calls use output buffers that do not overlap and in particular are not exactly the same.  The method for doing this varies (wildly) depending on the language you are using, which you didn't state and anyway is offtopic as noted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expected ciphertext is correct if you work with **no padding**. With PKCS padding the result is
`6D251E6944B051E04EAA6FB4DBF78465881572C3A96A612C111055707BD7614E`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you pls attach the link of AES CBC with PKCS padding test vectors

Comment: I have computed the given result with [CryptoStuff](http://jacquelin.potier.free.fr/CryptoStuff/) and [CryptoBench](http://www.addario.org/cryptobench/)

Answer (score 2):

As gammatester said, the ciphertext you're expecting is correct if you don't use any padding. When using a padding, if you try to encrypt a 16 bytes long message, it will append a full block of padding to your plaintext before the encryption start. 
Basically, you're encrypting `0000000000000000000000000000000010101010101010101010101010101010`
instead of the given plaintext.

Comment: There are couple of questions to clarify : would this padding value 10101010101010101010101010101010 differs based on padding method selected?

Comment: Here the length of cipher text becomes 32, If i would like to decrypt then what shall i pass the complete CT of size 32 bytes to get the plain text of size 16 bytes?

Comment: The padding will indeed be different if you use an other padding method. The one I mentioned correspond to PKCS7.

If you want to implement AES - CBC mode *with PKCS7 padding*, you should take care of the padding *and* the unpadding, so you should give the full ciphertext to the decrypting function (how can you guess how many bytes of padding there is ?)